# Change Button image from view controller inside custom header cell

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, swift5

I have a VC that is UICollectionView that has header. This header is a custom cell, and inside that cell there is an button with image which I need to change based on info from API or user tap.

In func loadData i get info about icon and then I call function inside headerCell to change the icon. Do I need to do this in other way in order for this to work?

```
    protocol HeaderCellDelegate: class {
        func setDropdown()
        func tapOnSelection()
    }
    
    class HeaderCell: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
        // delegate
        weak var hDelegate: HeaderCellDelegate?
    
        @objc
        lazy var selectionBtn: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.setTitle("One", for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeSelection), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()
        
        @objc
        lazy var oneOrTwo: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "oneOff")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleOneOrTwo), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()

        @objc
        lazy var iconBtn: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconGreen")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
             button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setIcon), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
            }()
        
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        
            // I setup view helper
            // Just a button and icon on the right
            // button opens DropDown list
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        // MARK: - Delegate Functions
        
        @objc
        func toggleOneOrTwo(_ sender: Any) {
            self.hDelegate?.setDropdown()
        }
        
        @objc
        func changeSelection(sender: UIButton) {
            self.hDelegate?.tapOnSelection()
        }
        
        @objc
        func setIcon() {
            isIconGreen
                 ? iconColor.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconGreen")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
                 : iconColor.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconRed")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        }

}
```

*ViewController*

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

  
    fileprivate let headerCellId = "headerCellId"
    lazy var headerCell = HeaderCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Register Cell Class
        self.collectionView.register(HeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerCellId)

        loadData()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerCellId, for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
            header.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
            header.hDelegate = self
            
            return header
        default:
            fatalError("This should never happen!!")
        }
    }

    func loadData() {
         // get data from API and isIconGreen value
         let isIconGreen = true
         headerCell.setIcon(isIconGreen: isIconGreen)
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work? What problem do you have now ?  BTW, I think you should call         DispatchQueue.main.async {collectionView.reloadData()} in order for loadData to do something

Comment: @Mat It doesn't work. I do collectionView.reloadData() when i get data from the API. The problem is when I access my headerCell and setIcon nothing happens. I'm trying now to access headerCell through viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind when i dequeue header cell.